# Call php function inside <td>

Tags: php, html

im having difficulties calling php function in my html table.

```
    <table>
        <thead class="table">
        <tr><th>Letter</th><th>Sender</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php require_once 'assets/userFunctions.php';
        foreach ($myCvs as $cv){
            echo "<tr>
            <td>{$cv['cv']}</td>
            <td>getUsernameById({$cv['senderid']})</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And in the table i just see `getUsernameById(2)` for example...

Answer (score 2):

you need to use concatenation:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $cv['cv'] . "</td><td>" . getUsernameById($cv['senderid']) . "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: I would add that the problem is not related to the `<td>` but actually "calling a function inside an `echo` statement in php".